# Why does Xcode make my Localized.strings file look screwed up like this?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, localization

When I click on the the en sub-file of that Localizeable.strings file which has a arrow to expand, I can't see what's written in that file. Screenshot:

[image: screwed up]

I can reveal the real file in finder and then see the real content in TextEdit with no problems. Then I copied that from TextEdit and pasted it into Xcode, and VOILLA all looks nice. Saved, build & run, and Localization stopped working. Damn.

Any idea what's going on? I created this in Xcode, and I clearly remember that once upon a time I was able to edit the contents with no problem from inside Xcode.

Comment: This is a UNICODE problem. The characters are being wrongly interpreted. Try saving the file in TextEdit in UTF-8 . Closing. Opening and copy/pasting again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is likely encoded in UTF-16. So, you can go to the Info for it (general pane) and set the right encoding for it.

Comment: Xcode asks me "Do you want to convert the file to the new encoding or reinterpret it using the new encoding"? Which would you pick? Convert or Reinterpret?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I would choose reinterpret... anyway, make a copy of the file if you do not have it under source control... if you have troubles, consider also opening it with an utf-16 capable text editor (like the free textwrangler).